# Замена текущего адреса на пуникод в джаваскрипте

Tags: javascript, share

Есть кнопки шаринга в соцсетях goodshare
функционал супер, но они не работают с кириллическими доменами - то есть не вытягивают кол-во шарингов в соцсетях
берется кол-во из такого кода
нужно преобразовать автоматом location.href в пуникод, а потом уже encodeURIComponent.

```
c.getJSON("https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url="+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+"&callback=?"
```

Кратко - как мне из урла заменить (что будет проще) адрес сайта из сайт.ру на xn--80aswg.xn--p1ag ?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй скопировать код с вот этого [ГитХаба](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js) (если точнее то: https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/blob/master/punycode.js) . Сам не пользовал, но в Интернетах на него много ссылаются. Сам автор собрал этот код переработав имевшиеся на тот момент реализации Пуникода и документацию (RFC 3492, RFC 5891), и как бэ позиционирует его как самый документируемый, производительный и покрытый тестами.

Исходный код красиво и грамотно оформлен, а главное прокомметирован через каждую строчку. Приведу только основную функцию `encode`, оболочку и декодирование можно додумать самостоятельно, даже если ГитХаб упал или автор уберёт проект из общего доступа:

```js
/**
 * Converts a string of Unicode symbols (e.g. a domain name label) to a
 * Punycode string of ASCII-only symbols.
 * @memberOf punycode
 * @param {String} input The string of Unicode symbols.
 * @returns {String} The resulting Punycode string of ASCII-only symbols.
 */
const encode = function(input) {
 const output = [];

 // Convert the input in UCS-2 to an array of Unicode code points.
 input = ucs2decode(input);

 // Cache the length.
 let inputLength = input.length;

 // Initialize the state.
 let n = initialN;
 let delta = 0;
 let bias = initialBias;

 // Handle the basic code points.
 for (const currentValue of input) {
  if (currentValue < 0x80) {
   output.push(stringFromCharCode(currentValue));
  }
 }

 let basicLength = output.length;
 let handledCPCount = basicLength;

 // `handledCPCount` is the number of code points that have been handled;
 // `basicLength` is the number of basic code points.

 // Finish the basic string with a delimiter unless it's empty.
 if (basicLength) {
  output.push(delimiter);
 }

 // Main encoding loop:
 while (handledCPCount < inputLength) {

  // All non-basic code points < n have been handled already. Find the next
  // larger one:
  let m = maxInt;
  for (const currentValue of input) {
   if (currentValue >= n && currentValue < m) {
    m = currentValue;
   }
  }

  // Increase `delta` enough to advance the decoder's <n,i> state to <m,0>,
  // but guard against overflow.
  const handledCPCountPlusOne = handledCPCount + 1;
  if (m - n > floor((maxInt - delta) / handledCPCountPlusOne)) {
   error('overflow');
  }

  delta += (m - n) * handledCPCountPlusOne;
  n = m;

  for (const currentValue of input) {
   if (currentValue < n && ++delta > maxInt) {
    error('overflow');
   }
   if (currentValue == n) {
    // Represent delta as a generalized variable-length integer.
    let q = delta;
    for (let k = base; /* no condition */; k += base) {
     const t = k <= bias ? tMin : (k >= bias + tMax ? tMax : k - bias);
     if (q < t) {
      break;
     }
     const qMinusT = q - t;
     const baseMinusT = base - t;
     output.push(
      stringFromCharCode(digitToBasic(t + qMinusT % baseMinusT, 0))
     );
     q = floor(qMinusT / baseMinusT);
    }

    output.push(stringFromCharCode(digitToBasic(q, 0)));
    bias = adapt(delta, handledCPCountPlusOne, handledCPCount == basicLength);
    delta = 0;
    ++handledCPCount;
   }
  }

  ++delta;
  ++n;

 }
 return output.join('');
};
```

Есть парочка интересных моментов, если собирёшься делать сам:

1. Сначала лучше проверить наличие не АСКИИ символов в хосте, если их нет, то можно вернуть как есть.

   `regexNonASCII = /[^\x20-\x7E]/; // unprintable ASCII chars + non-ASCII chars
   return regexNonASCII.test(string) ? 'xn--' + encode(string) : string;`
2. ДжаваСкрипт хранит строки в формате UCS-2, поэтому чтобы закодировать в пУникоде, надо сначала строку из UCS-2 раскодировать. `input = ucs2decode(input);`

Если погуглить немного, то найдешь и старый СО вопрос про то же самое (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion) где указаны и оригинал, и приведённый выше "оптимизированный" вариант.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/128723)

Comment: @Chubatiy, боюсь здесь не может быть "самого главного"
,. Скрипт с ГитХаба на 400 строк, нужная функция ещё на 100.

Comment: я понимаю. Можно привести краткое описание, какая функция/скрипт и куда именно обратить внимание, а не перерывать весь скрипт.